# Show custom taxonomy not in submenu

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, php, custom-taxonomy, admin-menu

I have one small problem and I can't find answer...I have created custom post type and custom taxonomy, but my custom taxonomy is showing as sub menu under custom pos type, here is  [example what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMa9Y.png) how can I do this??? here is how my taxonomy and post type is registered:

```
<?php

function inkodus_register_taxonomy() {
    // set up labels
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => 'Manufactures',
        'singular_name'     => 'Manufacture',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Manufactures',
        'all_items'         => 'All Manufactures',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Manufacture',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Manufacture',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Manufactures',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New Manufactures',
        'menu_name'         => 'Manufactures'
    );
    // register taxonomy
    register_taxonomy( 'manufactures', 'manufactures', array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'show_admin_column' => false,
        'show_ui'           => true
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\inkodus_register_taxonomy' );

function inkodus_create_post_type() {

    //setting up labels
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Furnitures-systems list',
        'singular_name'         => 'Furniture-system',
        'add_new'               => 'Add New System',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add New Furniture-System',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit System',
        'new_item'              => 'New Furniture-system',
        'all_items'             => 'All Systems',
        'view_item'             => 'View System',
        'search_items'          => 'Search furniture-systems',
        'not_found'             => 'Furniture systems not found',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'Furniture systems found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon'     => '',
        'menu_name'             => 'Furniture Systems
        ',
    );

    //registering post type
    register_post_type( 'furnituresystem', array(
            'labels'                => $labels,
            'has_archive'           => true,
            'public'                => true,
            'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor'), //'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail','page-attributes' ),
            'taxonomies'            => array('manufactures' ),
            'exclude_from_search'   => false,
            'capability_type'       => 'post',
            'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'furnituresystem' ),
            'register_meta_box_cb'  => 'add_attributes_metabox'
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\inkodus_create_post_type' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what you are trying is to add `manufactures` taxonomy for `product` post type of [Woocommerce Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/)?

Change `manufactures` object type to `product` and it should work.

```
register_taxonomy( 'manufactures', 'product', array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'show_ui'           => true
) );
```

Comment: I want add Manufactures as menu item with icon and so on..not as sub menu in Furniture systems menu

Comment: You can't register a taxonomy in the menu. It doesn't belong to any post type. So, what is it used for?

Comment: there is no other way to do display custom taxonomy in the menu?

Comment: Yes, no way if it is a taxonomy. Btw, what is it used for?

Comment: To create manufactures list

Comment: Why don't use custom post type instead?

Comment: Because I'm using custom post type furnituresystem and here im creating systems list, and in custom taxonomy im creating manufacturers list :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the taxonomy under products post type then you must change your code from.

```
register_taxonomy( 'manufactures', 'manufactures', array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'show_ui'           => true
) );
```

to

```
register_taxonomy( 'manufactures', 'products', array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'show_ui'           => true
) );
```

If you want to add this to multiple post types then use an array of post types.
See [register taxonomy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) for object type.

Also see [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) notes on taxonomy. If the taxonomy is not associated with the post type at the point of registration then this could issues when using filters such as `parse_query` or `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: I want add Manufactures as menu item with icon and so on..not as sub menu in Furniture systems menu